# Block all WAN access on Wi-Fi interface using DD-WRT

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I have a dd-wrt router with two Wi-Fi interfaces (`ath0`, `ath1`). I want everything that's on `ath0` to not have any kind of WAN access. Only LAN (to and from the device).

How would I do this in the easiest and most robust manner?

Before I've tried this using ath1 aswell by adding a virtual AP, a new bridge for the AP and some advanced routing and firewall settings. This was overly complicated though and I figured it should be a lot easier to just use my, unused anyway, `ath0` (5GHz) interface for this purpose.

I am using OpenVPN as a client which makes things a bit more complicated. When using iptables firewall with the old approach I would always have to manually re-set the firewall settings because a file in /etc/ is overwriting my rules (`-I` at the top) because of the VPN, allowing everything WAN access as long as its over the VPN. Because of squashFS I couldn't find a way to prevent that and always having to manually overwrite it after saving settings/rebooting the router isn't so nice. Also I'm not sure if it won't overwrite it again later.

I don't want `ath0` to have VPN access either. I can't use iptables with a source IP because it should be for all clients on that SSID/interface and as soon as they connect, so I won't really know an IP in advance.

I've tried looking this up but I couldn't find anything that'd work for my case except for the overly advanced virtual AP/bridge solution.

Comment: Hi @confetti, does ath0 have it's own subnet? In which case change the gateway IP so it is not what the devices expect (need to turn off DHCP in that case).  If they can't send packets to the GW they can't get to the internet .. Doesn't impact their LAN access.

Comment: @MrR It doesn't have it's own subnet. As of now, there's no special configuration on the router besides its use as a OpenVPN Client. I was considering to put ath0 on another subnet (or use a new bridge or something) so it has it's own IP range which I can block via iptables, but I'm not 100% sure what's the best way to do this and I also think there should be an easier/more robust way to do what's my end-goal..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have also `ebtables` (or `ebtables-nft`) in addition to `iptables` on the router, and that all the (W)LAN interfaces are bridge slaves to the same master (say named `bridge0`):

```
ebtables -I INPUT -i ath0 -j mark --set-mark 0xabcd
iptables -I FORWARD -i bridge0 -m mark --mark 0xabcd -j DROP
```

(Note that the mark value `0xabcd` is arbitrary.)

This causes all traffics that comes into the router from the "LAN side" to "stay within" the broadcast domain. The reason is, `ebtables`' `INPUT` does not include traffics that goes from a bridge slave/port to another (i.e. L2 forwarding). And for what targets the router itself (that comes from `ath0` and is henced marked), we don't want them to be forwarded on L3 (i.e. to be able to go from "LAN" to "WAN"/VPN/...).

As an alternative, you can do it without relying on iptables or packet marking as well:

```
ebtables -I INPUT -i ath0 -d Unicast -p ip ! --ip-dst $ROUTER_LAN_IP -j DROP
```

While not tested, `-d Unicast` is supposed to keep DHCP and so working. If you also need IPv6 (traffics *for the router on L3*) to work, you probably need/want an extra chain for more exceptions (which will allow you to allow DHCP with another approach as well), like:

```
ebtables -N ATH0
ebtables -A ATH0 -p ip --ip-dst $ROUTER_LAN_IP -j ACCEPT # unicast
ebtables -A ATH0 -p ip --ip-dport 67 -j ACCEPT # broadcast
ebtables -A ATH0 -p ip ... -j ACCEPT
...
ebtables -A ATH0 -p ip6 ... -j ACCEPT
...
ebtables -A ATH0 -j DROP
ebtables -I INPUT -i ath0 -j ATH0
```

But as you can see, the latter approach is much more clumsy.

P.S. I have zero experience with all of the WRTs or alike, so I have no idea how one should make xtables rules persistent on them. (To be fair though, AFAIK it's distro-specific anyway even on "typical" Linux distros.)

Comment: `ebtables v2.0.10-4` is installed. As for persistance, there's a UI to save firewall settings which should be used for this I  think. DHCP would be good, IPv6 isn't needed. So I assume I'd just need the first two commands? I'm a little confused by the first sentence. I have one bridge `br0` which is used for interfaces `ath0`, `ath1` and `eth1`. Would that be correct? There's no other bridge right now and no related settings differ from the factory defaults.

Comment: Yeah that sounds right. (And I suppose `eth0` is the WAN interface.) Yeah if you are fine without IPv6 you can try *either* the first or the second *code block* above and see if it does what you want.

Comment: `(W)LAN` above means `LAN and wireless LAN` btw, if that's what confused you.

Comment: I've tried the two commands (replacing `bridge0` with `br0`) but nothing seems to have changed. Both WAN and LAN still works just like before.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Not even the alternative in the second *command block* seem to do anything? Could you perhaps add the output of `ip a`?

Comment: The second approach works. Weirdly enough I think the first one worked too now (I've just kept the rules since yesterday, now I checked again => no internet. Then I removed them again => Internet.) but the second looks a bit cleaner anyway and the best part about it is that since its only ebtables it can NOT be over-ruled by that stupid /etc/.. script that made my previous own attempt unreliable. So I can use this in startup commands and have a reliable block that can't be overruled by a script's `iptables -I` anymore. Thanks!